# Is an always-on Android service ever not an anti-pattern?

Tags: android, android-service

I understand why an always-on service is normally an anti-pattern in Android, but my app really seems to be begging for one:

On first load, the app has to go through potentially thousands of small entities from the  database to construct the initial state. There's not much data brought into memory (most is lazy loaded later), but that first scan is unavoidable by the nature of the app. This scan can take at worst 6-7 seconds with slow hardware and a big dataset, average is probably around 3. The app is a "impulse use in short bursts" type of thing, so those repeated loads are really not desirable.

I think this begs for a background service to be perpetually alive and holding that state, thus avoiding that load time. It will always be ready to be killed, and not in the foreground, so should the system or user decide that they have it out for the service, no harm is done. But if the service is left in peace, the app will start instantly, and in my case that does a lot for the user experience.

Am I still wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think this begs for a background service to be perpetually alive and holding that state, thus avoiding that load time.

As the British say, bollocks.

> On first load, the app has to go through potentially thousands of small entities from the database to construct the initial state.

Then fix that. Either simplify this work, or persist the initial state in a simpler form for later reuse (e.g., JSON).

If it is OK for you to use a cached result of this work that is held in RAM, it is OK for you to use a cached result of this work that is held in an easier-to-read-in persistent data structure.

Comment: Exactly.  Once the startup scan is done, also store the results that are being held in memory in a non-volatile location (or do so in onPause).  If the app is destroyed and recreated should not have any bearing on the decision that the cached result of the scan is valid, or needs to be replaced by a new scan - that logic will be needed, but shouldn't depend on the activity lifecycle.

Comment: This approach crossed my mind, but one thing that I forgot to mention is that the calculation of the initial state depends on the current day, and I don't know when the user will next open the app. I could calculate, say, the next 5 days worth of states (could take a while), or use the alarm manager to wake the service every day and calculate the state. Either way, the solution is much more complicated than letting the service idle, and I see plenty of google services sitting around on my own device, which leads me to think that its not as bad as some make it out to be.

Comment: @tempy: "or use the alarm manager to wake the service every day and calculate the state" -- this would seem to be a fine solution, akin to using a cron job to statically generate content on a Web server rather than generate it dynamically on every request. "which leads me to think that its not as bad as some make it out to be" -- if that is your attitude, you are cordially invited to stop developing for Android. If you are not going to do your homework and read about the issues that users have with other Android apps, you should not be writing Android apps yourself.

Comment: Yeesh commonsware, I'm new to the platform and I'm just trying to differentiate the "not the greatest practice but passable if you're careful" stuff from the "NO REALLY don't do this," stuff. If I weren't interested in doing my homework I wouldn't be asking this question here in the first place. That said, you being you (I'm getting up and running with your books), I think I'll take your word for it. =P

Comment: @tempy: Sorry for going ballistic. There's been a run of developers with this sort of problem and taking the attitude that user opinion doesn't really matter. Hence, you rubbed a sore spot with your comment. That doesn't justify my over-reaction, for which I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

An "always-on" service would essentially act like a daemon process and there are plenty of services on Android phones that never turn off.

In this case, though, it seems a better solution would be to simply have a splash screen and/or wait dialog that sits there until the data is loaded.  It seems like a bad idea to me to take up resources when the app isn't running just so the app will load faster when the user finally opens it.  If the average use of the app is much smaller than the load time, then it would probably be even better to speed up the scan in some way.

Comment: I guess I'll just leave the answer.  I misread the question, but I think it still stands.  The way I see it is "always-on" services are fine only if the app absolutely needs it, the user is always aware of it's presence, and they're low in processing.

Answer (score 0):

People use taskkillers to kill such kind of services. My view is, that when you make the user aware of why your service is running (say, this will load the app quicker), he will understand it and not kill it. You could also ofcourse add an option to use the service or not.

Comment: This is a great point - I could turn the always-on behavior off by default, and then in the settings have a checkbox labeled something like "start-up boost." When the user selects it, I can show a popup explaining the service and asking the user not to kill it.